# How to execute a command after the previous non-terminating command prints a certain string?

Tags: bash, text-processing, control-flow

I want to execute `commandA` which prints the following:

```
line1
line2
line3
started successfully
line4
...
...
```

And when the line `started successfully` is printed I want to start another command (and possibly multiplex their outputs so that both are printed on the terminal).

How could I achieve this in bash?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the REST of the output from commandA, what you mean by "non-terminating" and whether this is a single shot or if there will be multiple instances.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way you can do that:

```
$ outputfile=output.log
$ commandA | tee "$outputfile" & tail --pid=$! -n+1 -f "$outputfile" |grep -q "started successfully" && commandB; wait
```

#### Explanation:

1. Using the `tee` command you write the output both to STDOUT and to the file named `$outputfile`.
2. You run the command in the background, so you could now track its output.
3. `tail --pid=$! -n+1 -f "$outputfile"` - You run `tail` command on `$outputfile` and follow its output starting from the first line.

   - The `--pid=$!` flag is required to ensure that the `tail` command terminates once `commandA` completes.
4. `grep -q "started successfully"` - will exit successfully (and quietly) upon the first occurrence of the required string.
5. `&& commandB` - if `grep` found the string, it will execute `commandB`.

   - You should use `&&` and not `;` to ensure that `commandB` is executed **only**  if the string was found in the output of `commandA`. If `commandA` finished without writing this string (for instance, if it failed), you don't want to run the second command.
6. `wait` - In case `commandB` finishes before `commandA`, keep waiting for `commandA` to run before returning to the shell.

   - Alternatively, you could run `fg` instead of `wait` to get to let `commandA` keep running in the foreground if `commandB` finished before.

#### Update

Inspired by @PaulPazderski's answer, here's another way to do that without a log file and the `tail` command:

```
$ commandA | tee >(grep -q "started successfully" && commandB; cat >/dev/null)
```

The only downside is that if `commandA` finishes **before** `commandB`, the shell will return to the prompt right after `commandA` finishes, while `commandB` might still be running in the background and even writing output to your terminal.

In order to solve this, just pipe the final output to another command, such as `cat`, to ensure that the shell returns to the prompt only when nothing writes to stdout anymore (which means that the entire command finished, even `commandB`).

```
$ commandA | tee >(grep -q "started successfully" && commandB; cat >/dev/null) | cat
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try a script "track-output" like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ "$line" == "started successfully" ]]; then
    do_something
    # optional exit but that could disrupt commandA with a SIGPIPE
  fi
done
```

and call it as

```
commandA | track-output
```

or if with `tee` and process substitution and without the echo line in the script as

```
commandA | tee >(track-output)
```

Comment: Nice, only notice that using the first method (without `tee`) you won't see both outputs at the same time. Once you get to the "started successfully" line, you'll stop see `commandA`'s output until the second command finishes. But using the second method it would work.

Comment: @aviro True, good addition. Could also run do_something in background as alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

```
{
  commandA 3<&- | perl -pe '
    exec "commandB <&3 3<&-" if !$pid && /started successfully/ && ($pid = fork) == 0;
    END {if ($pid) {wait; exit($? & 127 ? $? + 128 : $? >> 8)}}'
} 3<&0
```

If using zsh instead of bash, and GNU `tee`, you could do something similar with the caveat that `commandB`'s exit status will be lost with:

```
{
  commandA 3<&- |
    tee -p >(grep -q 'started successfully' && commandB <&3 3<&-)
} 3<&0
```

That would also work in bash (though you'd need to add a `exec` in front of `commandB` as `bash` doesn't always optimise out the fork there) except for the fact that `commandB` would not be waited for there.

In both approaches we take care that `commandA` and `commandB`'s stdin be left undisturbed. `commandA`'s stdout is changed from the original to a pipe, but that's necessary if we have to find `started successfully` in there, but that output is passed along by `perl -p` or `tee`. `commandB`'s stdout is undisturbed.

Note that some command *buffer* their output when stdout is not a terminal device. So with `commandA`'s output here becoming a *pipe*, you might find that `started successfully` is only printed as part of a large block, and `commandB` not started as early as it could be as a result.

With `zsh`, it can be worked around by using `zpty` to start `commandA` with its output connected to pseudo-terminal:

```
zmodload zsh/zpty

# start commandA with only stdout going to the pseudo-terminal
# stdin and stderr restored.
zpty A 'command A <&3 3<&- 2>&4 4>&-' 3<&0 4>&2

pid=
while zpty -r A line; do
  print -rn - $line
  if (( ! pid )) && [[ $line = *"started successfully" ]]; then
    { commandB <&3 3<&- & } 3<&0
    pid=$!
  fi
done
(( ! pid )) || wait $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will execute `command2`  after `command1` prints "Some text" (because on match grep will terminate). After that both  `command1` and `command2` outputs will be printed to stdout:

```bash
command1 | tee >(grep -o -m1 "Some text"; command2 )
```